# boostrap datepicker to show in h4 today as default using angular and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I am using Boostrap datepicker to get the selected  date in the calendar to put inside a `<h4>` html tag.

but what I would like to do is show today default already in the h4 when opens for the first time.

**angular.js + jquery**

```
   function link($scope, $element) {
      var $datepicker = $element.find('.date-picker').datepicker();
      $scope.TodayDate = new Date();
      $scope.activeDate = '';
      $datepicker.change(function() {
        $scope.activeDate = $(this).find('input').val();
        $scope.$apply();
    });
```

**html:**

```
<div>: {{TodayDate | date:"dd-MM-yyyy"}} </div>
<h4 class="pull-left" ng-show="activeDate">
              Active date: <span>{{activeDate}}</span>
</h4>
<div class='input-group date date-picker pull-right current-view'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

**edit**: I could get the today day, but the problem now is: when I select a day in the calendar show me 2 different dates. How can Update just the today date with the new date selected in the calendar?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular ng-init directive to display current date on page load. No need to get the date from date picker. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Then after the date loaded, you can click the date picker and using ng-click function, you can set date to your h4 tag. Otherwise without clcking the datepicker, it's a mess to take it's values.